# Expected value of one of two joint variables trick?

Tags: probability

The joint probability density function of X and Y is given by

$f(x,y)= \frac{6}{7} (x^2+\frac{xy}{2})$ for $0<x<1$ and $0<y<2$. ($0$ otherwise).

A: Verify that this is indeed a joint density function.

B: Compute the density function of X.

C: Find P[X > Y ].

D: Find P[Y > 1/2|X < 1/2].

E: Find E[X].

F: Find E[Y].

So I understand how I'd do A, B, C, D and E, and I see how E builds off of B... now I was just wondering if there was a trick I was supposed to notice/do for F, or am I just supposed to find the marginal probability of Y and then find E[Y] that way.

Comment: Indeed.  $\displaystyle\mathsf E(Y) = \int_0^2 y\int_0^1 f(x,y)~\mathsf dx~\mathsf dy$